# Brushing Subgraph in D3 Reporting Wrong Values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

**Task Description**

Report the brushed range of a brush event in d3. The task used http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 as a reference.

**Expected Behavior**

When I click or brush over the X or Y axis, the correct values should be reported, i.e. if I click over the number "0.3", d3.brush.extent() should return [0.3, 0.3]; if I brush over -0.2 and 0.4, d3.brush.extent() should return [-0.2, 0.4].

**Observed Behavior**

When I click over the X or Y axis, the correct value of d3.brush.extent() is observed in the console, i.e. if I click the number "0.3", d3.brush.extent() returns [0.3, 0.3].  However, when I brush a range, d3.brush.extent() fails to report the correct values there on out. The only way to restore the brush is by reloading the page. No errors are observed.

**My Attempts**

I've tried clearing the brush with d3.brush.clear(), but it seems to have no effect. If I brush a range, clicking a region that was observed to work before does not restore the brush.  From the reference above, the function that I believe is the culprit is

```
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
}
```

but I do not know why it is not behaving as expected in my application.

Here is a Plunker of what I have so far. Note that d3.brush.extent() values are logged onto the console.

http://plnkr.co/edit/B7i9QT7oZcPaXeybIfAB

**Questions**

Why does the brush event not return the correct range?  Why does it seem to get stuck when brushing? Any ideas as to what could be throwing the brush off?

Comment: Not entirely sure what's going on, but your `Graph` variable seems to refer to different things in different contexts. It works if you move the code you've defined in `d3_data` inside the `plot` function: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vrbba2kLDtfxuCQBODCU?p=preview

Comment: Hmm. I'm going to have to think long and hard about why it works this way. Meanwhile, thanks, Lars!